# How nodejs works with a callback

Tags: node.js, event-loop

here is some code, just as a example

```
obj.process('something', function(err, data) {
    dosometing(data);
});
```

why the callback function is executed, other than exit the program?

Node must save something. I know it must be related to event loop. but how? I got some about it from google but still puzzed.

thanks

**update**
since someone think this is unclear,  as @hereandnow78 said, I want to ask is **why the program is not exiting after obj.process and instead is waiting for the callback to happen**

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Maybe you can show a more real-world example and then more clearly describe the problem via an [edit].

Comment: i think his question is, why the program is not exiting after obj.process and instead is waiting for the callback to happen

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699619/when-does-nodejs-process-quit