# NodeJs program not exiting after completion

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Sorry for this noob question, I'm beginner in Javascript. I am using the NodeJs MySQL package to connect my node application to my database. But after running the query successfully the program doesn't exit it stays there forever until I terminate it manually. I want the program to run the query and exit the program.

The code that I'm using:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: "Hostname",
    user: "User",
    password: "Password",
    database: "DB_name",
    debug: false,
});

function sql_query() {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.code + ' : '+ err.sqlMessage);
            return;
        }

        var query = "MY-QUERY_STRING";

        connection.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {

            connection.release();

            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return;
            }

            console.log("Done");
            return results;
        });
    });
}

var result = sql_query();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to close the MySQL connection to exit the program. by using the following code in the success block you will exit the program.

```
pool.end(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('error:' + err.message);
  }
  console.log('Close the database connection.');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

As long as your pool is open, the node process will not exit. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699619/when-does-nodejs-process-quit) for further details.
If you want to close your pool after executing one query you can do the following:

```
...
connection.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
            pool.end(); // you can pass a callback here as well to handle errors
            ...
});
...
```

Also note that you're trying to assign the result of `sql_query` to `result`. This won't work as you can't return a value from a callback this way. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for further details.

Answer (score 3):

You have to close the connection with pool.end(), in your case you want it to be before returning `results`.

```
        connection.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {

            connection.release();

            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return;
            }

            console.log("Done");
            pool.end()
            return results;
        });
```