# Program does not terminate when running mySQL, error occurs when I close pool

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, pool, terminate

I'm testing MySQL locally with Node, and every time I run the file, the program doesn't end unless I manually terminate it (with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>). I searched online, and I especially looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61976788/nodejs-program-not-exiting-after-completion) (not a duplicate—it doesn't ask about my error), which said that the program will end if I call `pool.end()`. However, when I call the function, it gives me an error: `Pool is closed`, which leads me to believe that the pool is already closed. But then why doesn't my program end? My code looks something like this:

```js
// database.js
const mysql = require("mysql2");

const {HOST, USER, DATABASE, PASSWORD} = process.env;
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: HOST,
    user: USER,
    database: DATABASE,
    password: PASSWORD,
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 50,
    queueLimit: 0
});

exports.set = data => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.execute("INSERT INTO `mytable` (name, email) VALUES (?, ?);", [data.name, data.email], function(err) {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve();
    });
  });
};

exports.get = data => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `name`=? AND `email`=?;", [data.name, data.email], function(err, result) {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve(result);
    });
  });
};

exports.getAll = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM `mytable`;", function(err, result) {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve(result);
    });
  });
};

exports.end = () => {
  pool.end();
};
```

And then in my main file:

```js
const db = require("./database");

(async () => {
  const data = { name: "John Doe", email: "johndoe@example.com" };
  await db.set(data);
  const result = await db.get(data);
  console.log(result);
  db.end(); // I added this line as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61976788/nodejs-program-not-exiting-after-completion
})();
```

It gives the error `Pool is closed` with a stack trace. If I don't include the `db.end()` line the program just won't end (at the moment `db.end()` doesn't solve the problem either). Does anyone know the solution?

#### Update

As suggested in the comments, I installed a library called `why-is-node-still-running` to assess the situation, but the logs didn't make much sense. Here are the logs for reference:

```
There are 6 handle(s) keeping the process running:

TCPWRAP
C:\[REDACTED]\node_modules\mysql
2\lib\connection.js:45     - this.stream = Net.connect(
C:\[REDACTED]\node_modules\mysql
2\lib\pool_connection.js:7 - super(options);
C:\[REDACTED]\node_modules\mysql
2\lib\pool.js:51           - connection = new PoolConnection(this, {
C:\[REDACTED]\node_modules\mysql
2\lib\pool.js:139          - this.getConnection((err, conn) => {
C:\[REDACTED]\database.js:39
                           - pool.query("SELECT * FROM `registration`", function
 (err, result) {

DNSCHANNEL
(unknown stack trace)

GETADDRINFOREQWRAP
```

#### Update 2

When I put `db.end()` inside `setTimeout()` (without a provided delay number), `setImmediate()`, or `process.nextTick()` (in my main file), things work perfectly, no error is thrown, and the program ends normally. Although it works, I still didn't get to the root cause, so can someone tell me what happened?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but using a package like this can help you detect what's keeping the process running: https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-is-node-still-running

Comment: Thanks, but the logs weren't really helpful (I couldn't understand it...).

Comment: Consider editing your question and adding the logs. Me or others might understand them!

Comment: @Evert just did.

Comment: Hey @code, that's pretty interesting!. It looks like you actually still have a running query by the time you want to shut down. (`SELECT * FROM `registration`). Any thoughts why that might still be running?

Comment: @Evert Could it be the promise functionality?

Comment: possible, have you considered using mysql2/promise instead?  I wrote this article: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/ which may help!