# How does google V8 handles javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, v8, embedded-v8

I am trying to understand Google V8 javascript engine,
I went through https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started which lets javascript code be understood and executed. I am not getting how the events in javascript like Mouse click, Mouse over etc are interpreted by V8.
I came across   [Nodejs Event Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680601/nodejs-event-loop) and this
http://html5tv.rot13.org/JSConf.eu-Node.js.html , where later is the event loop for node.js can any point to something which can me a clear picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has no such things as events.

Stuff like mouse events in the browser are given by the browser DOM, not Javascript. In Google Chrome for example they are implemented in [WebKit/Blink](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/dom/Event.h)

Comment: What about canvas.addEventClickListener(event) this is in javascript how this is handled, i dont think this is handled in dom

Comment: @0'cool.. nope, this is what javascript has http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

Comment: I went through ecma standard, Still it has nothing to do with event. i just want to know that if i add any event listener in js how does v8(or any other js engine) understand that if any event is fired

Comment: @0'cool.. events are not in js engine but browser dom for example WebKit/Blink