# How to define setInterval function

Tags: javascript

I'm using V8 in conjuction with c++ and native window `setInterval` functon is not defined.

What would be an algorythm to create something like native `setInterval` but in pure js?

Comment: Since JavaScript itself doesn't provide a way to add tasks to the event queue, there isn't anything you can do with "pure" JavaScript. Maybe have a look at the V8 API?

Comment: Try look how nodejs implement the timers, maybe help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing setTimeout() and setInterval() in pure JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35824722/implementing-settimeout-and-setinterval-in-pure-javascript). See also [How is asynchronous javascript interpreted and executed in Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491385/how-is-asynchronous-javascript-interpreted-and-executed-in-node-js)

Comment: @RafaelDantas, in Node they use C functions for timers operations. https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/lib/timers.js

Comment: @DenisMatafonov i think that you cannot implement timers with pure js.

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50665051/104380

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `setTimeout` is available (not probable, but you did not specify that):

```
function setInterval(fn, t) {
  let id = {};

  function wrapper() {
    id.timeout = setTimeout(wrapper, t);
    fn.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  id.timeout = setTimeout(wrapper, t);

  return id;
}

function clearInterval(id) {
  clearTimeout(id.timeout);
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is not defined either, but thanks for the try