# Javascript- setImmediate() versus nextTick() for Stack or Message?

Tags: javascript

Using the Visual representation from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop:

Would one of the differences between `setImmediate()` and `nextTick()` be that `setImmediate()` places the code in the stack(current running code) versus `nextTick()` places the code in the next message(queue)?

[image]

Comment: are you talking about `node.js` runtime?  Also, is this a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15349865/798682 ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Both these methods are asynchronous, which means that the callback goes onto the queue and the stack is left alone (unlike as if it was called right away).

However, `setImmediate` and `nextTick` do use different queues. There are different execution cycles for them, and `nextTick` callbacks would all be invoked before the first `setImmediate`-scheduled one is. See also [setImmediate vs. nextTick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15349733/1048572) for details.

Comment: please explain you mean by that they use different queues. As far as I know, the event loop only has one queue that these api's work on.

Comment: Well, no. There are [multiple event loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680601/nodejs-event-loop), which you could think of "running inside of each other" (technically, it might as well be a single queue but with different insertion methods). As detailed in the linked question, `nextTick` callbacks will run before IO callbacks.